# .htaccess redirect https and automatically add www. if no subdomain exists

Tags: .htaccess, web

Need help,

for my site hosting at Planethoster, I tried to force the **HTTP** to **HTTPS** and without **www.** automatically with **https://www.**

With this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But the problem when I just use the url **mydomain.com** without **www.** it returns a strange url:
**https://www.mydomain. com/https:/mydomain. com/** (without espace before com)

So that I can not access my site with **mydomain.com** I have to manually put **www.**

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and put these rules at the top of your htaccess below `RewriteEngine on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force SSL and require www if no other subdomain.
You can try this,

```
# if ssl is off and starts with www or no subdomain,
# redirect to https://www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if ssl and no subdomain, redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if ssl off, and there's a subdomain that's not www,
# just use the current subdomain but redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can test them here, https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

These should cover all scenarios,

- http://example.com/abc
- http://www.example.com/abc
- http://abc.example.com/abc
- https://abc.example.com/abc
- https://www.example.com/abc
- https://example.com/abc

Comment: @AmitVerma care to comment why?

Comment: It matches if there's no SSL and if the host is either www.example.com or example.com. If that matches, it redirects to https://www... On the subsequent request, the only https on is matching if the domain is example.com, which it won't be.  It'll have https://www.

Comment: Sorry , I thought you are using [OR] with the first condition too. Your rule is good. +1.

Comment: @AmitVerma All good. Legit thought there was something wrong.